# font-face not showing on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I used font-face toolkit generated by font squirrel
I added this to my css and uploaded the webfont toolkit fully to my server, it is working perfectly everywhere except all mobile devices.

[www.x7turkey.com](http://www.x7turkey.com) (One stop...) that sentence is a good reference.

any help is really appreciated.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gilroy-regular';
    src: url('../fonts/gilroy-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/gilroy-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/gilroy-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/gilroy-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/gilroy-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/gilroy-regular-webfont.svg#gilroy-regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: This feels like an excuse to post a spam link that seems pretty irrelevant to the rest of the question. I'm not completely certain but I don't see why else this link was included in the question

Comment: If the link was an attempt to show a website that isn't working correctly then the better thing to do would be to include a screenshot and an [mre] here rather than relying on people having to go look at an external website to see the problem

Comment: @DavidW They seem to be using that site as an example for what they want but I am not sure. I flagged the question as unclear.

Comment: Please inspect your site via dev tools. The font file URLs/paths are wrong – you'll see 404 logs (check your templates directory structure). Just fix your paths and everything is fine. Your `@font-face` syntax looks fine - albeit you can safely ditch 'eot' and 'svg'.

Comment: @DavidW it is my first question here at stackoverflow so pardon the beginners mistakes, the website is not to promote anything or a spam it is my legit website, I included it so you can open it both on desktop and mobile devices to see the difference, next time I will take the rules into consideration.

Comment: @herrstrietzel thank you very much, you opened my eyes on the errors after hours of checking everything, I forgot that I put the font on my server with a link only accessible to admin while logged in, so that's why it was showing on my desktop only, I will upload them to public accessible URL. Thanks!

Comment: @AdelDvedar I read it a few times and decided I didn't think it was meant as a spam link, so sorry for the accusation. It's definitely better to try to make your questions answerable without links, but I know it isn't always easy

Answer (score 0):

Your main src should be the `ttf` format (most widely supported font format), the `eot` format is supported only on IE.

https://caniuse.com/?search=eot

Comment: didn't work....